# "No database selected"

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

So I am having trouble inserting data into my database. The current error I have is a "No database selected" error but I can't see where the issue is. My code is:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_test");

// Check connection

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$firstname=$_POST['firstnameReg']; 
$surname=$_POST['surnameReg'];
$mypassword=$_POST['passwordReg']; 
$email=$_POST['emailReg'];


$result= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_customers (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', '$mypassword'");

echo "$firstname", "$surname", "$mypassword", "$email";

if($result)
{
    echo "Success!";
}
else
{
    die(mysql_error());
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Can you see any errors? I know it's not protected against SQL injection, it's just a test project. Thank you.

Comment: have you used mysql_select_db(your database name); in your code??? also close one bracket after insering values before "(double quotes)

Comment: dont use mysql and mysqli both in your code. try to write it in mysqli ith PDO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `mysql_query` which is from the wrong library, you should use **[`mysqli_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)**

```
$result= mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_customers (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', '$mypassword'");
```

So in your case, you're also missing the closing parenthesis from the `VALUES`:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO tbl_customers (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', '$mypassword')");
```

Taking the opportunity you should also implement prepared statement to avoid SQL injection:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_customers (firstname, lastname, email, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
if (!$insert = $con->prepare($sql))
    die('Query failed: (' . $con->errno . ') ' . $con->error);

if (!$insert->bind_param('ssss', $firstname, $surname, $email, $mypassword))
    die('Binding parameters failed: (' . $insert->errno . ') ' . $insert->error);

if (!$insert->execute())
    die('Execute failed: (' . $insert->errno . ') ' . $insert->error);
else
    echo "Success!";

mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You sir, are amazing. This fixed all issues. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're using both `mysqli` and `mysql` in your code. You can and should only be using `mysqli`.

Comment: I see. I am new to this so I have looked at a number of different tutorials. Is there an easy fix for this particular issue?

Comment: The mysql functions all have mysqli equivalents. The manual will tell you about each of them. They're *almost* identical.

Comment: I fixed it by adding my $con to the start of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Go to php.net and find each `mysql_` syntax you want to use in `mysqli_`.

Every warning you see, that the `mysql_` syntax is deprecated, shows the function that is going to be used instead.

For instance: `mysqli_connect()` replaces both `mysql_connect();` and `mysql_select_db();` (asks for server and database in one function).

Don't worry about editing, almost all the important functions are (almost) the same so you don't have to edit that much.